# Keep certain part of lines in file

Tags: python, file

I'm wondering how to keep certain numbers in a log file, eg:

```
[05:38:42] The temperature is 20 Celsius.
[05:39:10] The weather is cloudy.
[10:20:21] The temperature is 18 Celsius.
[10:20:42] The weather was is sunny.
```

Where I only want to keep the number 20, and remove everything else.

So far I've only managed to keep the specific line that contains the temperature:

```
file = open('file')
with file as f:
    for line in f:
        if "temperature is" in line:
            print(line)

>>> [05:38:42] The temperature is 20 Celsius.
>>> [10:20:21] The temperature is 18 Celsius.
```

However I would want it to only print:

```
>>> 20
>>> 18
```

Comment: Have a look at [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `re`:

```
import re

lines = ['[05:38:42] The temperature is -20 Celsius.',
'[05:39:10] The weather is cloudy.',
'[10:20:21] The temperature is 18 Celsius.',
'[10:20:42] The weather was is sunny.']

for line in lines:
    match = re.search(r"is\s(-?\d+)\sCelsius", line)
    if match:
        print(match.group(1))
```

Output:

```
-20
18
```

**EDIT** Updated to work with negatives.

Answer (score 0):

This only works for the positive number, In case I missed anything please let me know.

```
file = open('file')
with file as f:
    for line in f:
        if "temperature is" in line:
            for number in line.split():
                if number.isdigit():
                   print(number)
```

Comment: Would this also show the numbers in the timestamp? Also where is number defined?

Comment: It wont show anything because it errors out because you don't define number anywhere.

Comment: `number` was defined in the 5th line, please see the code again.

Comment: You are passing a function an undefined variable, not defining number.

Comment: Taking out line 5 makes it run.  However does not work for negative numbers.

Comment: I am not getting you. can you please in another way?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165534/discussion-between-kvk30-and-chrisz).

Comment: @chrisz It was mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of `.split()` and a comprehension:

#### Code:

```
numbers = sum(
    [[int(x) for x in datum.split() if x.isdigit()] for datum in data], [])
```

#### Test Code:

```
data = """
[05:38:42] The temperature is 20 Celsius.
[05:39:10] The weather is cloudy.
[10:20:21] The temperature is 18 Celsius.
[10:20:42] The weather was is sunny.
""".split('\n')[1:-1]

numbers = sum(
    [[int(x) for x in datum.split() if x.isdigit()] for datum in data], [])
print(numbers)
```

#### Results:

```
[20, 18]
```

Comment: I like the comprehension here.  Just a note, negative numbers won't be picked up.

Comment: hey, Stephen can you please tell me what changes need to be done in my code?

Comment: What?  I am missing some context here.  What are you asking?

Comment: @StephenRauch I also did the same thing but chrisz is saying it is the wrong approach. I was asking you to review my code so that I can improve the code.

Comment: @kvk30 I'm not saying this is the wrong approach, I think it's good, just noting that negative numbers will not be picked up using this method.